# linkedin from python : unable to send multiple messages

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I want to send messages to multiple friends in linkedin using python.
from docs : http://code.google.com/p/python-linkedin/
Using this one can send that.

```
result = api.SendMessage("This is a subject", "This is the body", ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"])
```

But I am not able to use that. Can anyyone tell me what is ID1? ID2? etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only message first degree connections. So, to get valid ids, I'm guessing the code looks something like:

```
>>> connections = api.Getconnections() # connections is a list of Profile instances
>>> connections
>>> [<linkedin.linkedin.Profile object at 0x1a3d510>]
>>> connections[0].id
>>> 'js6vz2-D6x'
>>> result = api.SendMessage("This is a subject", "This is the body", [connections[0].id, connections[1].id, connections[2].id])
```

Comment: means u cannot send messages who are not connected in connect list?

Answer (score 1):

They are the ID's for the people you wish to send a message to. instead of `['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']`, try using `send_yourself = True`  to make sure what you are doing works. So it will be:

```
result = api.SendMessage("This is a subject", "This is the body", send_yourself = True)
```

Comment: yes i can send to myself. I have done with that. but I am not able to send messages to ID's of peoples. Can you please elaborate peoples which IDs with example?

Comment: You can only message first degree connections. I pasted some code in as an answer because I couldn't find a good way to format it as a comment.

Comment: what do u mean by first degree connections?

Comment: ok i understand what is mean by first degree connections. but then if i can send messages only to first degree connections through api, then whats the use of it?

Comment: That is how the LinkedIn site works. It's similar to how you can only DM followers on Twitter.

Comment: oh ok. i thought using command u can do all those things which i can do from web. :(

Comment: oh ok it means if my account is upgraded, i can send mail using python api to others?